# Reading unread emails with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have the below code to read emails and check if the subject is matching with the expected message

```
 Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
    String message="Thanks for contacting"; 
    if(folder.getUnreadMessageCount()!=0)
    {
            for (Message mail : messages) 
            {
                if(!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN) && mail.getSubject().contains("Thanks"))//if mail is unread and the message matches
                {
                    mail.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
                    softAssert.assertTrue(true,"Email received ->");
                    Reporter.log("Email received ->" + mail.getSubject(), true);
                    break;
                            
                }
                if(!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN) && !mail.getSubject().contains("Thanks"))//if mail is unread and the message does not match
                {
                    System.out.println(mail.getSubject() + "-> is not the email we are looking for");      
                    
                }                       
            }           
        
    }
    else
    {
            softAssert.assertTrue(false,"Email not received");
            Reporter.log("Email not received ->" + message, true);
    }
```

The problem is I want to fail this test if both the conditions inside the for loop fail. if i put the else inside the for loop it prints not received for reach element in the loop. how do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boolean` expression. See the below simple example,

```
   boolean test = true;
   boolean test2 = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (!test) {
            System.out.println("Test value is false.");
        } else {
            test = false;
        }
        if (!test2) {
            System.out.println("Test2 value is false.");
        } else {
            test2 = false;
        }
        if(!test && !test2) {
            System.out.println("Breaking loop.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Create two `boolean` variables and set their values as `true` incase if your `if` condition fails inside the loop then by using `else` block change the `boolean` value to `false` and do the same for your second `if` condition as well. In the last `if` condition if both statements fails then `break` the loop.

Comment: Its breaking out of the loop in the first go it self because this loop reads even read messages.

Comment: The solution purpose is to give an idea of how to deal `The problem is I want to fail this test if both the conditions inside the for loop fail.`